# Robocopy From Folder A - Only differences between Folder A and Folder B, to Folder C?

Tags: script, cmd.exe, robocopy

I have a system setup where 2 folders on separate drives / locations are normally mirrored via DFRS. This works perfectly and I have no issues with this.

However, the system that owns these files (a record management system) is being upgraded, and whilst that is happening, we need to put this DFRS on hold for about a month.

Whilst we still have daily backups, this puts us at risk, as we could potentially lose a days worth of data if the system / folders died or got corrupted.

What I would like to be able to do, is something like Robocopy to compare the primary folder, with the secondary folder, and copy anything that has been modified, added or updated, to an entirely new folder, and retain the file / folder structure. This will help immensely in the event of dr or bc being invoked.

Is there a way to do this, that I can tie to a scheduled task?

Regards

Comment: It would be relatively straightforward to do this in PowerShell I think. I could hack some code together to get you started if you like.

Comment: I have been advised by our apps team that there are limitations with using powershell on these particular machines - but if you could give it a try, that would be great.

Comment: What sort of limitations? If it's not going to work, then there is no point trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Though this issue seems over and dealt with, [here is a post that deals with a similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/748069/how-do-i-compare-two-folders-recursively-and-generate-a-list-of-files-and-folder). It features a few ways to do things actually.